# sql : how to split data from field in pentaho report designer

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

In database say I have a product named X. This product have a category.
I am trying to split data from field name 'Category'.

for example
**Product : X**
**Category : AA,BB,CC,DD**

product and category located in different object.
the result that I want is like this :

[in report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hulMn.png)

how to get the value of the field one by one and store it to each column of that category of the product?

Comment: do you want is Sql server also

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the sql query itself ( depends on an rdbms you are using ).
Also you can try report scripting (js or groovy).